# Prevent UITableViewCell's UIImageView from resizing asynchronously loaded UIImage

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, asynchronous, uiimageview

I'm asynchronously loading `UIImageView`s in my `UITableViewCell`. My image views are squares of 100 points by 100 points, but the `UIImage`s that I retrieve do not always have equal widths and heights.

My problem is this: upon loading the cells, the `UIImageView`s are all 100 by 100, which is good, but the inner `UIImage`s are stretched to that size (left image). When I press down on the cell and it is highlighted, **the images SUDDENLY RESIZE to the right proportions** (right image). Also, when I scroll down further into the `UITableView`, all the images are also 100x100 and stretched, but when I scroll back up to see the cells again, they are suddenly resized already. I don't know the scaling ratio they are following, though.

[image]

What am I doing wrong? I've already set the `UIImageView`s' `contentMode` to `UIViewContentModeCenter` but as you can see, it's not working. Please help? My full code is below.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"searchResultCell"];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"searchResultCell"];
    }

    // Get the Ad object that will be displayed in this cell.
    Ad *ad = (Ad *)[self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Set up the detail text on the right.
    cell.textLabel.attributedText = ad.attributedTextDisplay;
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

    // Set up the image on the left.
    NSString *thumbnailURL = ad.thumbnailURL;
    NSData *data = [FTWCache objectForKey:[MD5 hash:thumbnailURL]];

    // If the image has been previously downloaded and is stored in FTWCache.
    if (data) {
        // Then use that data instead.
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    } else {
        // Assign default image before beginning background image retrieval task.
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image_stub_ad"];

        // Trigger background task that retrieves the actual thumbnail from the URL.
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:thumbnailURL]];

            // Proceed only with updating the table view cell if the returned NSData is not nil.
            if (imageData) {
                dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    // UPDATED: Added call to setNeedsDisplay.
                    UITableViewCell *theSameCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                    theSameCell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                    [theSameCell setNeedsDisplay];
                });
            }
        });
    }

    // UPDATED: Set the contentMode to UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit instead of UIViewContentModeCenter.
    cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: In your statement below "// Set the contentMode to ...": `[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath].imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;`  the cell is likely still `nil` -- which is the whole purpose of the delegate: return a cell for that index path. You may change it to: `cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;`

Comment: instead of this
**`[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;`**
use this
**`cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;`**

Comment: ^Thanks you two, I did just that. However, when the images lack width, they still move to the left upon highlighting/scrolling. The same isn't true for images that lack height though, so long as their widths can fill the entire 100 x 100 area. I'm pulling out my hair now...

Comment: One problem was the nil cell returned from `[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]`, the other is related to the view mode. You MUST however invoke `[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]` in the completion handler after you get the image data from remote!

Comment: **`cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];`**

Comment: yes, and don't forget to _change_ the contentMode in the completion handler if the real image is such different from the "placeholder" image which requires it's own contentMode, or if the cell hasn't been setup at all.

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't a completion handler for a call to `dataWithContentsOfURL:`, where should I place that? Do you mean I should use a `NSURLConnection` synchronous request instead? (I've also updated my code above to reflect its current state).

Comment: Well, there is: the "poor mans" completion handler you created is the block you call on the main queue after you asynchronously dispatch the remote access. ;)  Your code could be improved, though: use NSURLConnection's asynchronous fetch method, or better use NSURLConnection and implement the delegates. You may need this anyway when you discover the more subtle inherent issues with this approach.

Comment: I just set the content mode right after the `if (imageData)` line and the images still move to the left. :( I guess I should just resize the thumbnails.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
// Proceed only with updating the table view cell if the returned NSData is not nil.
            if (imageData) {
                dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                   UITableViewCell *imageCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]

                    imageCell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                   [imageCell setNeedsDisplay];//this is the line I added only

                    [FTWCache setObject:imageData forKey:[MD5 hash:thumbnailURL]];
                });
            }
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't change anything. :(

Comment: I did that just now. I commented out setting the content mode to `UIViewContentModeCenter` and set it to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` before my call to `setNeedsDisplay`. The good news is that it seems to have stopped the stretching, but when I highlight the cells or scroll down and back up, the cells move to the left if they are lacking in width.

Comment: Just try it outside for setting mode to imageView..I think this will help you.

Comment: I put it back outside, and followed the comments' tips to use `cell` instead of `[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:...]`, but the images still move to the left upon highlighting/scrolling when it is lacking in width. Images that lack in height seem to be OK though, so long as their width fills up the entire 100 x 100 area.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ImageViewCell *cell = (ImageViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"identifier"];

    if (cell==nil)
    {
        cell = [[UImageViewCell alloc] init]; //or from whatever way you generate this cell.

        //Manually set this below on each time the cell is newly created.
        cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    }

    //Do the update of your imageView's image here 
    //( this is the update area when your cell is not nil 
    // and could be a reused cell.)

    cell.imageView.image = your_ui_image ;
    [cell.imageView setNeedsDisplay];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, but an "improvement" of triggering the remote fetch in an asynchronous  task:

```
    // Trigger background task that retrieves the actual thumbnail from the URL.
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request 
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] 
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse* response, 
                                               NSData* imageData, 
                                               NSError* error) {
         if (error) {
              [self handleError:error];  // connection failed
              return;
         }
         // here, at a minimum, check status code and Content-Type:
         // ... add code
         if (statusCode == 200 && contentTypeOK)  // "OK"
         {
             [FTWCache setObject:imageData forKey:[MD5 hash:thumbnailURL]];
             [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].imageView.image = 
               [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
         }
         else {
             // we didn't get an image, possibly other errors (e.g. authentication, etc.)
             NSError* err = ...;  // add code
             [self handleError:err];
             return;
         }
    }];
```

This code lacks the possibility that it can be cancelled if this is required. There is also no means to prevent starting multiple requests for the same image.

The above issues together with a certain user scenario may cause the app to spawn an unlimited number of running network requests - which will eventually cause the app to crash due to memory issues. To improve this, we need to utilize `NSURLConnection` implementing the asynchronous style with delegates - which gives us a chance to cancel the request, and take additional measurements that multiple request will not be called.

#### Edit:

An additional improvement would be to perform the insertion of the image data into the cache and also the creation of the `UIImage` object on a background task, whose completion handler updates the cell and executes on the main thread.